# manipulate the decimal without the main number

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to figure out how to fix this problem.
I am greeting my time in this format (15min is 25% of an hour) such as

```
8.75 mean 8:45
7.50 mean 7:30
```

I wanted to come out with a simple function to fix that issue But I wasn't successful, any thought?

Comment: show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can do it

```js
function calc(number){
  const decimal = number.toString().substring(3, 4)
  parseInt(decimal)
  const result = decimal*60/100
  return number.toString()[0] + ':' + result + '0'
}

console.log(calc(8.75))
```